# How to use Android's MediaBrowserService to serve MediaStore songs?

Tags: android, cursor, mediastore, android-livedata, mediabrowserservice

In the 'onLoadChildren' method of the MediaBrowserService we must return a list of MediaItems in order for the client to build it's UI accordingly. How would I go about it if in my service I have a cursor I just fetched from the MediaStore, or an instance of LiveData I just got from say a room DB?

I can't understand how to convert my cursor/live data into a list of media items (without iterating all the cursor/LiveData data of course),  or how will the client know when it needs to fetch some more data from the service?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally found a solution to my problem.
I used the Android new [Paging library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/) in order to request pages of MediaItems from my service. This way I don't iterate through all my cursor's records, and just fetch the MediaItems the user wants to see.

I wrote a [blog post](https://medium.com/@shevach/how-to-paginate-mediabrowserservice-e4fdc902ff2) about it where I go into details and provide code samples demonstrating the solution.